# Dynamically unbind events from multiple elements using jQuery (Equivalent to dojo.forEach(this.connections, dojo.disconnect);)

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-8, unbind

Ok here is what i do.

I use jQuery to connect events to my controls like below:

```
$("#id").click(function(){ 
   //do something 
});
$("#id-1").click(function(){ 
   //do something 
});
$("#id-2").click(function(){ 
   //do something 
});
```

What i want now is to be able to unbind those events dynamically when the page unloads, liko so:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
   //unbind events here
});
```

I use the following to gather all my events in an array:

```
events = new Array();
events.push($("#id").click(function(){ 
   //do something 
}));
```

Now on unload i want to iterate through the "events" array and  disconnect all the events from the controls.

I used to do it like below, but that was dojo:

```
dojo.forEach(this.connections, dojo.disconnect);)
```

In the above code block "this.connections" is an array like "events" i used above.

So is there a way to do something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? browser will automatically will do that as  window is closing.

Comment: The `.click()` function returns a jQuery object (for the purposes of chaining), so what you're actually storing in the Array is a list of jQuery objects (each of which will contain a single element) and not a list of events.

Comment: Not too sure but my guess is to prevent memory leaks from circular references?

Comment: @Shusl As **Salketer** said IE8 has some issues with circular references. It will not remove the events that are connected to a control if that control is outside the DOM tree for some reason. That is why i want to do that to be sure that no control has any events connected to it before unloading the page so i wont have orphan nodes that will lead to memory leaks

Comment: @AnthonyGrist `.click()` is not the only event I am attaching it's just an example here. The problem is described in my previous comment.

Comment: @Solon My point was that you're working on an incorrect assumption that your Array contains events - it doesn't, it contains jQuery objects with references to DOM elements. All of the jQuery event binding functions - `.click()`, `.change()`, `.on()`, etc - **all** return the jQuery object that they were called on for the purposes of chaining. If you want to remove *all* event handlers, of any type, you can simply iterate over that array of jQuery objects and call `.off()` on them.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thank you, I will try it and let you know! Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it...

```
   events = new Array();
   events.push({selector:"#id",eventName:"click"});
```

And then

```
$(window).unload(function(){
   $.each(events,function(elem){
       $(elem.selector).off(elem.eventName);
   })
});
```

You save the selector and eventname in your array so you can access them later. And simply delete the handlers one by one. Might not be the most efficient but it works.

Comment: Hey Salketerm It does not seem to do anything good. It actually gives me more leaking elements.

Comment: There shouldn't be any leak in this part of code... Make sure you do not save the DOM resource link but the selector only. Also, slower but foolproof would be $('*').off();

Comment: Hey @Salketer, as i can see most of the leaking elements are DIVs! How would that be?